# How to retrieve the attendance index of a place from google map using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have just started practising Flutter, I am currently working on a Flutter application, and my mission is to collect the attendance of a place using Google Maps (the number of people who are in a place). Can you help me please because I have no ideas at the moment?

Comment: you can use packages from [flutter package](https://pub.dev/)  this one is for [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) of the user and [map](https://pub.dev/packages?q=map) just by reading the documentation you can use it easily

Comment: I will try thnak's

Comment: You can check out  this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter/). It shows how to retrieve map data from a web service and display that data as markers on the Map.